# Displaying arraylist values from servlet in jsp in tabular format

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, iteration

I am trying to display students data in a table in jsp after fetching from database

**Students Servlet**

```
ArrayList student = new ArrayList();
String selectSQL = "SELECT studentname from student";

while (rs.next()) {
    studentname = rs.getString(1);
    student.add(studentname);
}

request.setAttribute("student", student);
request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").include(request, response);
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%
    ArrayList List = new ArrayList();
    String student = (String) request.getAttribute("student");
    List.add(student);

    Iterator<String> itr = List.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
%>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Students</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%=itr%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<%
    }
%>
```

somewhere wrong in home.jsp part. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your servlet, this

```
ArrayList student = new ArrayList();
```

should be

```
List<String> student = new ArrayList<>();
```

**please** don't use raw types. Then, in your jsp

```
List<String> al = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("student");
Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
```

**and**

```
<%=itr%>
```

should be

```
<%= itr.next() %>
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot for help.. I am putting ur code..will be back

Comment: hi in jsp I am getting only one student name but not all, where I am wrong in servlet plz help me

Comment: @Tom Try a debugger. First make sure you are reading more than one student with your query, then you might to examine your html; you appear to be building an entire table per student.

Comment: ok thanks I am doing.. many thanks for your help..will remain grateful to u

Comment: u r right there was only one data

Comment: please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646322/how-to-get-current-value-of-itr-next-in-servlet