# how to get current value of Itr.next() in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, iteration

I am trying to get current students roll no by clicking on "View Marks" button but unable to do so, I am doing somewhere wrong.

home.jsp// displaying student roll numbers

```
  <%
     List<String> al = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("student");
           Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
        %>        
   <table>
   <tr>
  <th>Student Roll No</th>
  </tr>
  <%  while(itr.hasNext())
       {
   %>

  <tr>
         <form action="studentmarks" method="POST">

  <td><%= itr.next() %></td> //displaying 50 student roll numbers

 <% String s=(String)itr.next(); %>// If I add this line then I am getting 
     only one same record printed above instead of 50 records which were 
  getting printed, I am unable to understand this why this is happening?

      <input type="hidden" name="studentrollno" value="<%=s%>"/>// 
 I want to pass current student roll no to studentmarks servlet , but here 
 only same student's roll no getting passed to servlet in stead of current 
 student roll no

   <input type="submit" value="View Marks"/>
      </td>     
  </form>
 </tr>

   <% }%>
  </table>
```

studentmarks servlet

```
  String studentrollno=request.getParameter("studentrollno");
   out.println(studentrollno);//showing same students roll no instead of 
 different student
```

I am doing somewhere wrong. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: where am i wrong pls anyone guide me?

Comment: Can we see the rest of `studentmarks` servlet? Is that code in the `doPost` method?

Comment: hi in doPost studentsmarks servlet I want to print current selected student's roll number. But what I saw is if I put the line String s==itr.next(); and passing <%=s%> as hidden parameter then I am getting only one record displayed in jsp in stead of 50 records, thats d puzzle I am unable to understand,  ur help will be much helpful to me here

Comment: Which question are you asking? How to display 50 records, or how to get current students roll no by clicking on "View Marks"? You need to debug your code, and if you're still stuck, you need to post a [Minimal,Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, you need to clarify which question you are asking.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have edited my question please have a look

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how to get current students roll no by clicking on "View Marks"?

Comment: Post the contents of your `List`. Again, **please** make a Minimal, Reproducible Example. We can't run this. Also, every time you call `itr.next()` it consumes a record. Right now you consume **two** per row.

Comment: ok...............